# What does this string represent as a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, rhino

Given the following data being fed into a javascript engine (like rhino):

```
{
  hello=66.66,
  whygod=sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeArray@7ba28183,
  sku=[2490748],
  world=sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeArray@69e4fede,
  price=[]
}
```

1) What kind of objects do the **sku=[2490748]** and **price=[]** represent in javascript?

I would have thought that they were arrays but it doesn't seem like that because when I run the following logic as part of the javascript engine that processes this data,  price does not get removed:

> ```
>     function doStuff(row) {
>         var price = row.get( 'price' );
>         if ( price == null ||
>              price == '' ||
>              price.length == 0)
>         {
>             row.remove( 'price' );
>         }
>         return row;
>     }
> ```

2) So then what is it, any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rhino, but Object Literals in JavaScript do not have a `get('key')` method.  That may be the root of your problem.  FWIW, `[]` is most definitely an Array.

Comment: Javascript object literals do not use the `=` sign. You do it with a `:` like this: `hello: 66.66`.

Comment: @JosephSilber - Good catch.  Without a call signature I missed the equal signs.  The `[]` is definitely still an array.  I presumed it was an Object because he seems to believe he's passing it around as `row` in his `doStuff()` call.  There's something odd here.

Comment: Have you tried to see what `typeof price` outputs? Also there is a missing comma after `hello=66.66` which, even after you change the ='s to :'s, will make your code fail

Comment: @Martin, I manually formatted the data to be on separate lines and ended up removing the comma, I've edited the question now to fix that. Also this is a string representation of a Map being fed into the Rhino javascript engine which is why you see =s instead of :s. I had tried typeof price and it keeps saying its an object and no more info so that feels like a dead end. is there a way to get it to spit out the object's keys maybe?

Comment: if typeof shows it's an object, that's good, means it is probably an array like it should be. Try to see what output `a.constructor.name` gives you or just `a.constructor.toString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the java side before being fed into rhino javascript engine, I found out that price=[]  was a mapping of the key called price to an ArrayList object with only one empty string object.

Afterwards, spitting out the key/value pairs of the price object on the javascript side showed me that ***it wasn't really any type of standard javascript object at all***!

I spit out both **price** which should have had an empty string and **sku**. Now at least the **sku** should have had the value **2490748** somewhere in its key/value map dump but it didn't! Sigh ... no idea how to work this thing.

Other than the empty:false property nothing seems useable. But I thought it merited a mention:

> sku=
>
> empty: false
>
> indexOf: function indexOf() {/* int indexOf(java.lang.Object)
>   */}
>
> notifyAll: function notifyAll() {/* void notifyAll()
>   */}
>
> removeAll: function removeAll() {/* boolean
>   removeAll(java.util.Collection)
>   */}
>
> trimToSize: function trimToSize() {/* void trimToSize()
>   */}
>
> containsAll: function containsAll() {/* boolean
>   containsAll(java.util.Collection)
>   */}
>
> contains: function contains() {/* boolean contains(java.lang.Object)
>   */}
>
> equals: function equals() {/* boolean equals(java.lang.Object)
>   */}
>
> notify: function notify() {/* void notify()
>   */}
>
> subList: function subList() {/* java.util.List subList(int,int)
>   */}
>
> class: class java.util.ArrayList set: function set() {/*
>   java.lang.Object set(int,java.lang.Object)
>   */}
>
> isEmpty: function isEmpty() {/* boolean isEmpty()
>   */}
>
> add: function add() {/* void add(int,java.lang.Object) boolean
>   add(java.lang.Object)
>   */}
>
> ensureCapacity: function ensureCapacity() {/* void ensureCapacity(int)
>   */}
>
> size: function size() {/* int size()
>   */}
>
> iterator: function iterator() {/* java.util.Iterator iterator()
>   */}
>
> clear: function clear() {/* void clear()
>   */}
>
> wait: function wait() {/* void wait() void wait(long) void
>   wait(long,int)
>   */}
>
> listIterator: function listIterator() {/* java.util.ListIterator
>   listIterator(int) java.util.ListIterator listIterator()
>   */}
>
> retainAll: function retainAll() {/* boolean
>   retainAll(java.util.Collection)
>   */}
>
> toString: function toString() {/* java.lang.String toString()
>   */}
>
> hashCode: function hashCode() {/* int hashCode()
>   */}
>
> toArray: function toArray() {/* java.lang.Object[]
>   toArray(java.lang.Object[]) java.lang.Object[] toArray()
>   */}
>
> lastIndexOf: function lastIndexOf() {/* int
>   lastIndexOf(java.lang.Object)
>   */}
>
> addAll: function addAll() {/* boolean addAll(java.util.Collection)
>   boolean addAll(int,java.util.Collection)
>   */}
>
> clone: function clone() {/* java.lang.Object clone()
>   */}
>
> get: function get() {/* java.lang.Object get(int)
>   */}
>
> getClass: function getClass() {/* java.lang.Class getClass()
>   */}
>
> remove: function remove() {/* java.lang.Object remove(int) boolean
>   remove(java.lang.Object)
>   */}

Answer (score 0):

If this is a function block delineated by the outside braces as in this:

```
function init()
{
  hello=66.66
  whygod=sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeArray@7ba28183,
  sku=[2490748],
  world=sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeArray@69e4fede,
  price=[]
}
```

then:

```
sku=[2490748]
```

is assigning an array of length 2490748 to the variable sku.  To know for sure, we'd have to see a little more context around the code you presented.  You can see some diagnostics on the `sku` case in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KFgwF/.

If sku isn't defined in a local scope, then it's implicitly being declared as a global variable (because no `var` in front of it.

```
price=[]
```

is assigning an empty array to price.

---

### Edit based on your comment:

If you are expecting this to be a data structure that gets passed to a function:

```
{
  hello=66.66
  whygod=sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeArray@7ba28183,
  sku=[2490748],
  world=sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeArray@69e4fede,
  price=[]
}
```

Then, that is simply not legal javascript.  For that to be a legal data structure declaration, it would have to look like this:

```
{
  hello: 66.66,
  whygod: "sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeArray@7ba28183",
  sku: [2490748],
  world: "sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeArray@69e4fede",
  price: []
}
```

Comment: Actually sku is assigned an array of length 1 with the value `2490748`.

Comment: @jfriend00 The data is a string representation of a java HashMap that gets fed into Rhino. Also I just don't know what kind of object price=[] ends up becoming once Rhino gets a hold of it. Whatever it is, it certainly fails to match any of these conditions: price == null || price == '' || price.length == 0

Comment: What do you mean "fed into Rhino"?  I thought Rhino was a stand-alone javascript execution environment.  It runs javascript without a browser.  You should be running legal javascript in Rhino, right?   I told you what I thought price was in my answer.  Do you have reason to believe that isn't true?  An empty array should have price.length == 0.

Comment: "Fed into rhino" means that a javascript method is being invoked in the stand-alone execution environment and that it takes the data as its argument. Since it takes the data as its argument, that data is being "fed into Rhino" by the java code that asks rhino to run the javascript method on the data for it. Yes I do have reason to believe that "price" is not an empty array, that reason being the fact that the condition price.length == 0 does not match once javascript runs on the data.

Comment: OK, if you're expecting that to be a data structure that gets passed to some function, then it's not legal javascript.  I added info onto my answer that shows you what it would have to look like to be a legal data declaration.

Comment: But that's just how the code invoke rhino, the code in jave calls upon the rhino engine with arguments that are also in java and that's just how this integration works. I understand that there may be other integrations or method calls that rely on passing this data as a javascript formatted string, the way you suggest, but that is not what is happening here and this is what I'm forced to work with as the code is not in my control. So what you're saying isn't helping me and what I'm working with isn't wrong.

Comment: If this isn't javascript and it's something that will processed by your app/engine before being turned into javascript, then I will bow out of this conversation as I know nothing about that environment.  I thought this was a javascript question (it's tagged as such), but apparently not.